# How to extract image urls using jSOUP?

Tags: java, html, image, jsoup

I am sorry if my question is a bit stupid, I am pretty sure I am missing something here, as I am newbie in JAVA :(

I am trying to extract and download the images from the URL.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<a class="MYCLASS " href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/123456789">
<img src="//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/NEEDEDIMAGE.jpg" width="70" height="46" alt=""></a>
```

So first I get the link using "href" attribute :

> "https://www.flickr.com/photos/123456789"

And then I parse the HTML document by the previously obtained link , looking for image files.

The part with getting original URL of the image in the class "MYCLASS" works perfectly fine, but when it comes to extracting image URLs from the link that I get, it gives me "org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException" no matter what I try to change..so I will post the part of the code which definetely contains some error,,

```
Elements srcs = doc.select("a.thumbnail.may-blank");

              print("\nLinks: (%d)", srcs.size());

                for (Element src : srcs) {
                    String url1 = src.attr("abs:href");
                    Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url1).get(); //I believe this line has a problem..
                    Elements imgs = doc1.select("img[src$=.jpg");
                    print("\nIMAGES: (%d)", imgs.size());

                    for (Element img:imgs) { 
                        String url2 = img.attr("abs:src");
                        System.out.println("url = " + url2);
                        saveImage(url2); 
                        }
                }
```

Stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException:
>   Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or
>   application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=image/jpeg,
>   URL=https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Ebi.jpg
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:547)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
>   at HTML.main(HTML.java:44)

**UPDATE:**

I changed `Elements imgs = doc1.select("img[src$=.jpg");` to  `Elements imgs = doc3.select("[src]");`

Now it throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Malformed URL: url1   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:78)   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:38)   at
>   org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)    at HTML.main(HTML.java:45)
>   Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: url1  at
>   java.net.URL.(URL.java:586)     at
>   java.net.URL.(URL.java:483)     at
>   java.net.URL.(URL.java:432)     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:76)

However, if I change "url1" in `Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url1).get();` to a specific url, I get the "org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException" again.

I will appreciate any idea or hint! ㅜㅜ

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the full stack trace (which should include the actual MIME type Jsoup doesn't like).  Is the exception thrown when retrieving an HTML document, or the image itself?

Comment: Updated with exception stack trace. I think it happens while trying to get the HTML document. Before I used URLConnection and then just parsed the obtained document using jSOUP. But this time I decided to do it with jSOUP, because it seems like shorter..

Comment: Problem is most probably with your `saveImage` method post that code and we might be able to help you... Rest of your code is okay...

Comment: Thank you. If I comment the save method, it still throws the exception,,so I believe the error  is somewhere above :(

Comment: Can you mention what url's DOM is `doc` object holding?

Comment: jSoup doesn't know what to do with `.jpg` images. It can only handle HTML and XML documents. That's the source of your MIME type error.

Comment: @christopher , for example "https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/107367563/m%3D2048/cb818817f02bdc31cb4dfd63e665ff2f  here 's the link ,,it is the HTML document, but I still get the same exception

Comment: Looks like an image to me. [And to my browser too](http://i.imgur.com/b1SMGTI.png). That IS the image you want. jSoup has nothing to do with that. You need to save that image. Not try to parse it with jSoup.